# TinyMCE v6.7.1 Issue: mceAddEditor not working

Tags: javascript, tinymce

When using TinyMCE v4.7.12, I'm adding editor dynamically to a textarea like this and it is working

```
var comment = 'G' + count + '_fee';
setTimeout(function () {
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, comment);
}, 100);
```

I upgraded TinyMCE to v6.7.1 and the above code doesn't work, I get following error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'external_plugins').

I came across this https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/migration-from-5x/#mceaddeditor-and-mcetoggleeditor and modified the command as follows

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEdit', false, { id: comment });
```

Still same error and editor is not added to textarea. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in case you're still struggling with this, what worked for me was explicitly defining the `options` option. i haven't looked into it too much but i believe the error is caused when the `options` option is undefined since it may not have a default set for it so `tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEdit', false, { id: comment, options: {} });` should get you up and going.